# Rails geocoder - geocoding for registered and guest users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, devise, rails-geocoder

I've got an app that uses rails geocoder to find locations of registered users by their provided zip code. This works well for registered users, but I also want to extend some functionality to guest users. I'm using devise's solution for guest users as shown in this link: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

validates :zip, presence: true
geocoded_by :zip
after_validation :geocode

end
```

Here's my `create_guest_user` method:

```
def create_guest_user
    u = User.create(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => false)
    session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
    u
end
```

I want to geocode a guest_user's location by their IP. Is there a way I can call a geocode method in my `create_guest_user` method and then pass the values of lat and long when the guest user is created? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing a condition to geocoded_by? I browsed through the docs for an example and couldn't find one, but it's worth a try at least.

```
class User
  geocoded_by :ip_address, :if => :name == "guest"
end
```

If that doesn't work, you can define a new method to geocode by (like in the example given for address [here](http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/frames)):

```
class User
  validates_presence_of :zip, :if => non_guest #(or however you define a real user)
  geocoded_by :zip_or_ip
  after_validation :geocode

  def zip_or_ip
    if name == 'guest'
      :ip_address
    else
      :zip
    end
  end
end
```

and then get rid of the :validate => false in your controller (or keep it if you need to for other things).

Comment: This worked, thank you! I went ahead and used created a method like your second suggestion. I couldn't figure out a clean way to define a real user in the `validate_presence_of` line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cool! Well, I don't really know what all you're doing with users, but I guess the easiest way would be 'if: :nonguest' and 'def non guest

Comment: whoops pressed enter. def nonguest / self.name != 'guest' / end